# Tiny Parts of my Character are not moving when i move my whole armature. there are not even a vertices there either

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature

This is my first post here so tell me if I'm doing something wrong

My character When I move the central bone

[image: My character when I move the central bone]

Answer (score 0):

I would reposition the character, selected the character and remove doubles. I know you said that there are no vertices there but something has to be there I would think.

Comment: sorry, that didn't work